# Typing junk values on real devices using appium

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

I am working on apk automation using appium tool and my script is working fine on emulator but when I run on the real device then the email address and password don't get typed as expected. It entered some junk values.

Not only me but many of the team members are facing the same issue.

These are more other required details:

- Appium version: 1.7.1
- Java-Client : 5.0.4
- Java 1.7

Phone details:

- Samsung Galaxy A5 ( OS : 6)
- OnePlus

Appium Code:

```
public void loginInApp(String EmailValue, String PasswordValue) 
{ 
    objAndroidGenericMethods.enterTexAndroidElement(getEmailtxt(), EmailValue, "entered the email/ username "); 
    objAndroidGenericMethods.enterTexAndroidElement(getPasswordtxt(), PasswordValue, "Entered the password"); 
}


public void enterTexAndroidElement(AndroidElement element, String textValue, String reportContent) {
    element.sendKeys(textValue);
}

public AndroidElement getEmailtxt() {
    emailtxt.clear();
    return emailtxt;
}

public AndroidElement getPasswordtxt() {
    passwordtxt.clear();
    return passwordtxt;
}
           // Objects for email & Password
@FindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@index='0' and @resource-id='com.test.android:id/et_email_address']")
public AndroidElement emailtxt;
@FindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@index='0' and @resource-id='com.test.android:id/et_loginregister_password']")
public AndroidElement passwordtxt;
```

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Comment: How do we know that the value from the screenshot is not the actual value of `EmailValue` variable? (By the way: by convention, java variables don't start with uppercase character, unless it's a constant (in which case, its whole name is typed in upper case)).

Comment: because I have written the script and debugged also, and the text shown in the screenshot are similar to the actual input but with missing text. and also, the same script will work on OnePlus